# bad operand types for binary operator '<='

Tags: java, if-statement, boolean, logical-operators

```
class First {  
   public static void main(String[] arguments) { 
      int x =60;  
      if (51 <= x <= 9) {   
         System.out.println("Let's do something using Java technology.");
      } else { 
         System.out.println("Let's");
      }
   } 
}
```

I am getting the error and I cant understand why as I am new to Java and programming.

> bad operand types for binary operator `<=`

```
if (51 <= x <= 9) {
   first type:  boolean 
   second type: int
1 error
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How Java works for: `51 <= x <= 9`
`51 <= x` is calculated first which results to a false (boolean) in your code.
Then the result of that is tried with `<= 9`.
And therefore the error, "<= not valid for boolean and int".

As suggested in other answers you will have to use `&&` (and) operator. For Example:

```
if (x <= 51 && x >= 9) {
    //do something
}
```

As you can see in my answer I have used both less than and greater than, which helps in reading code. Read as if `x` is less than equal to 51 and `x` is greater than equal to 9 then.

Hope this helps in explanation.

Answer (score 4):

Use this code instead of yours to fix problem

```
51 <= x && x <= 9
```

Your trouble is because first comparison returns boolean value and after you compare it with int value. It's wrong.

Comparison is a binary operation, that processed from left to right one by one.

Answer (score 2):

You should use logical operator `&&` meaning **and**. Others are `||` meaning **or** and **negation** `!`. You can make various combinations using these operators and brackets `()`.

Your condition should be like this one:

```
if (51 <= x && x <= 9) {
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using syntax from another language (Python maybe) in Java you need to do:

```
if (51 <= x && x <= 9)
```

example

```
int x = 60;
        if (51 <= x && x <= 9) {
            System.out.println("Let's do something using Java technology.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Let's");
        }
```